# Pseudocode for loop index starts with 2

Tags: c, pseudocode

How should I write a better pseudocode for a for loop where its index starts with 2?

```
for(i=2; i<n; i++)
```

I want it to be formatted like this

Code:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Pseudocode

```
FOR each element in the array
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you're asking. Your first piece of code seems fine, but again, I don't really understand the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: If you change your pseudocode into "FOR EACH element in the array, except the first (and the second) one", then your code looks perfect.

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: "for each element of the array starting at 2"

Comment: More importantly: what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to write this, depending on the situation, but i would suggest you to write: "For i = 2 upto n"

Doing this, the reader knows that "i" will go up to "n" and be incremented each iteration.

You can also write: "For i = 2 to n", if the value of n is given as higher than 2 earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

For all values of `i` starting at 2 and less than `n`